# Is there a way to query what functions a class has?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

With tools such as std::is_base_of, std::is_arithmetic, etc, is there a way we can, at run time, check if a function is available to a type?

e.g.

```
template<typename T>
void function( T arg )
{
    static_assert(std::has_function<T, "DoSomething">::value, "Type must have function DoSomething!");
    arg.DoSomething();
}
```

Or something along those lines?

Comment: Just note that if you check for a `size` member function you'd want to avoid accepting a `bool`-valued one. Also, checking accessibility is a problem.